# How to mount a SMB share to local folder - not only a drive letter - using powershell

Tags: powershell, smb

Is it possible to mount a SMB share (or any other network share) to a local folder with powershell - apart from using "net use"?
I tried `New-SmbMapping` and `New-PSDrive`. But I get errors for both.
This is what I tried with `New-SmbMapping`

```
New-SmbMapping -LocalPath E:\MOUNT\pro\ -RemotePath \\host.example\projects
```

I get `the specified device name is invalid` and:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_SmbMapping:ROOT/Microsoft/...MSFT_SmbMapping) [New-SmbMapping], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 1200,New-SmbMapping
```

And for `New-PSDrive`, it seems not possible at all.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `New-SMBMapping` to create a mapping to a local folder - only to a drive letter. The "device name is invalid" error refers to the fact that `E:\MOUNT\pro` is not a valid device letter (it expects a single English letter).

To mount an SMB path into a local folder, you need to create a "junction point" - what Powershell calls `SymbolicLink`. For example:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path mytest -Target '\\computer\share'
```

The local path (`./mytest` in the above example) must not exist as `New-Item` needs to create it (this is unlike file system mapping in other operating systems).

Your current user must have access to the remote share, otherwise you'd get a non-helpful error message such as `New-Item : Cannot find path '\\computer\share' because it does not exist.` You can access shares for which you need to provide a user name and password by first loading the credential with `net use` before running `New-Item` (I don't know of Powershell way to do `net use`).